# What kind of cable is this?

Tags: switch, fiber

I need to cost out some switching and figure out how to network a PC to this type of network.

[image: One end]

[image: Terminated]

Clarifying: This is to connect units in a high rise facility. Each unit has the top picture in a closet. In every other floor in the hallway the cables from two floors are brought together in a panel. Then each panel sends a cable to the basement.

So I'm trying to figure out how to

1. Attach a PC (via cat5) at the apartment level.
2. Concentrate the signals from the units at the hallway level and send this down to the basement where it would get sent to a server.

Comment: I will add that there is a 17.23% chance--depending on how tight that cable tie is in the picture and how many times people have tugged on the connector--that the fiber is now "marginal" and should be metered before use.

Comment: in nutshell it is Optical fiber

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's not a network - that's just the physical medium. More information [is on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_fiber_connector).

The type of connectors you have on top are LC, the connectors you have on the bottom are SC.

---

LC:

[image: LC connectors]

---

SC:

[image: SC connectors]

Comment: +1 Side note, Orange is OM2 fiber. Aqua is OM3, "better" than OM2 and capable of higher speeds. Yellow is single-mode fiber, used for long distance situations usually.

Answer (score 5):

SC multimode fiber.

Generally you don't network a computer directly into fiber (although you can buy HBAs for PCs).  Normally Fiber is used as a backbone for your network.  Switches then connect to this fiber, and connect out to PCs over copper/RJ45.